# Can Console.Clear be used to only clear a line instead of whole console?

Tags: c#

While working on a question/answer program for school, it occurred to me that I can use `Console.Clear()` to wipe out everything on the screen. I wonder if I can use `Console.Readline(valueOne)`, then output only the answer without the question. If I only asked one question, the `Console.Clear` works.

I have several questions with values not references, to erase if possible. I want to leave out the questions and only display several answers. I think if I store the answers, I could use `Console.Clear()` then just `Console.WriteLine()` with three variables. I could do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value 1 is: {0:c}" + "Value 2 is: {1:c}" + "Value 3 is: {2:c}, valueOne, valueTwo, valueThree).
```

The problem is easier with references because the values are stored and retrieved. If I simply use methods to pass by value and output the value, `main()` will not have a reference to those values to clear and output again. That's why I wonder if I can just ask a question, then erase the line and output only the answer (or answers).

I am just trying to understand the possibilities and not trying to setup a program. I like to know the abilities of outputting a value from reference and by value without extra output questions.

Comment: I am only a 3 week student of c# by the way.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm having difficulties understanding your use of "answer" and "question" - what are they and what are you building? And what is your question?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

#### Description

You can use the `Console.SetCursorPosition` function to go to a specific line number. Then you can use this function to clear the line:

```
public static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
{
    int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth)); 
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, currentLineCursor);
}
```

#### Sample

```
Console.WriteLine("Test");
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
```

#### More Information

- [Console.SetCursorPosition Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition.aspx)

Comment: This code should probably use `Console.BufferWidth` instead of `Console.WindowWidth`, since it's possible there will be characters written outside of the visible window area.

Comment: Why does taking `(Console.CursorTop - 1)` not cause an out of range error? I'm looking at the C# source for [SetCursorPosition](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,114298628fe9afcf,references) and it looks like it uses 'int' which would make the number -1. I see that it doesn't use an unsigned integer, so why doesn't it throw an error?

Comment: @TheFluffyRobot because `Console.CursorTop` returns the current line, so `Console.CursorTop - 1` returns the previous line. Since there is a `Console.WriteLine("Test");` before, the current line will never be 0.

Answer (score 62):

A simpler and imho better solution is:

```
Console.Write("\r" + new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth) + "\r");
```

It uses the [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) to go to the beginning of the line, then prints as many spaces as the console is width and returns to the beginning of the line again, so you can print your own test afterwards.

Comment: For me it worked only with Console.WindowWidth-1:  `Console.Write("\r" + new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - 1) + "\r");`

Answer (score 19):

"ClearCurrentConsoleLine", "ClearLine" and the rest of the above functions should use Console.BufferWidth instead of Console.WindowWidth (you can see why when you try to make the window smaller). The window size of the console currently depends of its buffer and cannot be wider than it.
Example (thanks goes to Dan Cornilescu):

```
public static void ClearLastLine()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.BufferWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
}
```

Comment: This should normally be a comment to the respective post(s) as it doesn't answer the question by itself.

Comment: I cannot answer to their posts when I do not have enough reputation, I cannot contact the authors of the comments, due to not finding their emails and there is no point of spamming the same (not original) solution in my answer.

Comment: if (Console.CursorTop > 0) Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

```
static void ClearLine(){
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth)); 
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

My preferred method is to use PadRight. Instead of clearing the line first, this clears the remainder of the line after the new text is displayed, saving a step:

```
Console.CursorTop = 0;
Console.CursorLeft = 0;
Console.Write("Whatever...".PadRight(Console.BufferWidth));
```

Comment: `(BufferWidth -1)` to not overflow the line.

Answer (score 4):

We could simply write the following method

```
public static void ClearLine()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
}
```

and then call it when needed like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Test");
ClearLine();
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

To clear from the current position to the end of the current line, do this:

```
    public static void ClearToEndOfCurrentLine()
    {
        int currentLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
        int currentTop = Console.CursorTop;
        Console.Write(new String(' ', Console.WindowWidth - currentLeft));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(currentLeft, currentTop);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void ClearLine(int lines = 1)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= lines; i++)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer so that it would be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found why there are a few varying answers for this question. When the window has been resized such that it has a horizontal scroll bar (because the buffer is larger than the window) Console.CursorTop seems to return the wrong line. The following code works for me, regardless of window size or cursor position.

```
public static void ClearLine()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - (Console.WindowWidth >= Console.BufferWidth ? 1 : 0));
}
```

Without the (Console.WindowWidth >= Console.BufferWidth ? 1 : 0), the code may either move the cursor up or down, depending on which version you use from this page, and the state of the window.

Answer (score 0):

This works perfect for me as i expected -

```
    public static void ClearLine()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest solution I came to:

```
var cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
Console.CursorLeft = 0;
Console.Write(new string(' ', cursorLeft));
Console.CursorLeft = 0;
```

Writing the whole `Console.BufferWidth`, not `Console.BufferWidth - 1` may result in moving to the next line, depending on the console.