# Return user to point of data entry C# Console application

Tags: c#, validation

In the example below, assuming the user enters a negative number, how can I bring the cursor back to the same place where the user entered an invalid number so that the program can continue on?

```
Console.Write("Enter a number for the factorial: ");

int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if (k < 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number that is greater than or equal to zero");
}
```

Comment: what happened when you typed "C# move cursor in console window" into a search engine?

Comment: what do you mean by " bring the cursor back to the same place where the user entered an invalid number"?

Answer (score 0):

i think this will meet your requirement

```
string errormessage="Please enter a positive number; previous input was invalid";
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number: ");
        int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        while (k < 0)
        {
            Console.Write(errormessage);
            //get back to the input line
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop-1);
            //Clearing the previous input
            for (int i = 0; i < k.ToString().Length; i++)
                Console.Write(" ");
            Console.Write("\r");
            k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        //Clearing the error message
        for (int i = 0; i < errormessage.Length; i++)
            Console.Write(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("\r");
```

sorry not the prettiest of code but does the job!

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing the methods in this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console), I believe you can solve your issues.  Basically just copy the ClearConsoleLine method and use the Console.SetCursorPosition to move to the desired line/column.