# C# console stay on same line after confirming int

Tags: c#

I have literally started c# today and I have hit a block.

I am following beginner guides on YouTube but I have not found my answer yet.

What I am trying to get is the question below, all on the same line:

"what is * divided by *"

---

but what I am getting is:

what is * (here at this point I press Return to confirm the digits which I think is my problem)

divided by * (really here is the only place I want to be hitting return)

```
Start:
  int num03;
  int num04;
  int answer;

  Console.Write ("what is "); 
  num03 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ()); 
  Console.Write ("divided by "); 
  num04 = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

  Console.WriteLine ("");
  Console.WriteLine ("is the answer? ");
  answer = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());

  if (num03 / num04 < answer) {
    Console.WriteLine ("a bit lower next time");
    Console.WriteLine ("");
    Console.WriteLine ("");
    goto Start;
  } else if ( num03 / num04 > answer ) {
    Console.WriteLine ("a bit higher next time");
    Console.WriteLine ("");
    Console.WriteLine ("");
    goto Start;
  } else if ( num03 / num04 == answer ) ; {
    Console.WriteLine ("correct!!! please try another");
    Console.WriteLine ("");
    Console.WriteLine ("");
  }

  goto Start;
```

I think the hardest part is trying to search the correct phrase for help when I get stuck.

Comment: A tad off topic maybe but I would have a read up on `goto` and maybe consider replacing your `goto` construct with a loop.

Comment: In most cases manipulating the Input other than the standard way of using `Return` key, will be the wrong and dangerous way, Specially for a beginner. I will suggest you otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with this requirement, the <kbd>Return</kbd> key is a **very** standard way of entering input. The `ReadLine` function reads until this character is encountered.

You have two options:

1. **Read the keys in a loop**

You would do this by calling `ReadKey` instead of `ReadLine` in some sort of while loop. The big problem here is you need *some* delimiter to determine the end of input, and whatever it is, the user won't be expecting it.

2. **Mess with the console cursor**

Not a terrible idea, but also not really a good practice to be trying to learn as a novice. You can do this with `Console.SetCursorPosition` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx))

Honestly, I would just leave it as is, maybe change your input format so it makes sense on multiple lines. It will be what your users are expecting anyways.

Comment: Thank you - i did not expect such a quick response - i have spoken to a friend who suggested trying setcursorposition but i don't think my couple of hours of expertise is ready just yet

Comment: @JakeRyan Since you are new, I would learn a few input norms, like a new line terminating the input. You don't need to bother with `SetCursorPosition` because you *dont need to move the cursor* the newlines are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Can Console.Clear be used to only clear a line instead of whole console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console)

You can clear the last line of the console and print it again with the new information, or be creative with the options available by moving the cursor.

EDIT: I just realized that the problem was much simpler than I had expected, but I will leave this answer here in case it is of use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Bradleys answer with a example:

As you can see the cursor left is set with the length of "What is " plus your answer.
Also the top is made 1 higher which compensates for your enter. I wouldn't recommend ReadKey since you have lots of scenarios where you have to catch backspace etc.

```
Start:
        int num03;
        int num04;
        int answer;

        Console.Write("what is ");

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        num03 = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        Console.CursorLeft = "what is ".Length + input.Length;
        Console.CursorTop--;
        Console.Write(" divided by ");
        num04 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("is the answer? ");
        answer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (num03 / num04 < answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a bit lower next time");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            goto Start;
        }
        else if (num03 / num04 > answer)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("a bit higher next time");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            goto Start;
        }
        else if (num03 / num04 == answer) ;
        {
            Console.WriteLine("correct!!! please try another");

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }

        goto Start;
```