# How to clear specific lines of text in c# console application

Tags: c#, text, console-application

I have 3 lines of text, how do I clear line 1 and 2 without affecting Line 3?

We have 3 lines of text: One is just a static text line that appears, another is the timer which is counting down and the third line is text that the user will input in to the console application. When we were typing, the text in the third line was vanishing within a couple of seconds - We would like this text to stay and not vanish

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a code example? You need to provide more information before anyone can provide a solid answer to your problem.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8946847/1149773

Comment: We have tried: console.SetCursorPosition, 

We have 3 lines of text: One is just a static text line that appears, another is the timer which is counting down and the third line is text that the user will input in to the console application. When we were typing, the text in the third line was vanishing within a couple of seconds - We would like this text to stay and not vanish.