# C# Console Clear Input Line

Tags: c#, console, prompt

I have a C# console program that asks the user for a certain word by showing a input prompt.  The input is then processed using an switch statement. If the word is correct, the program continues.  But if the input doesn't match, the program says "Error: invalid input" and then goes back to the input prompt.  The tricky part is that I want the program to *clear* the input that the user just typed before pressing Enter and prompt the user again, without making another separate prompt below the first one.

Is there a library of some kind in C# that does something like that, or do I have to make a library for it?

Comment: Kindly read this post: [Can Console.Clear be used to only clear a line instead of whole console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code you currently have (that's relevant to this question).

Comment: Pro Tip, There is a reason we don't write code in natural language. because natural language is ambiguous and not precise. In short we need to see your code not a description, empirical evidence and concrete examples 99 times out of 100. Anything else makes it hard for us

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use a combination of `Console.SetCursorPosition` and `Console.Write` to set the cursor to the beginning of their response, write enough whitespace to "erase" their reaponse, and then set the cursor back to the beginning again.

For example:

```
static string GetUserInput(string prompt, List<string> validResponses)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);

    // Capture the cursor position just after the prompt
    var inputCursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
    var inputCursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    // Now get user input
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    while (validResponses != null &&
           validResponses.Any() &&
           !validResponses.Contains(input, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        // PadRight ensures that this line extends the width
        // of the console window so it erases itself each time
        Console.Write($"Error! '{input}' is not a valid response".PadRight(Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.ResetColor();

        // Set cursor position to just after the promt again, write
        // a blank line, and reset the cursor one more time
        Console.SetCursorPosition(inputCursorLeft, inputCursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', input.Length));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(inputCursorLeft, inputCursorTop);

        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Erase the last error message (if there was one)
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));

    return input;
}
```

In use this might look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var validResponses = new List<string> {"Yes", "No"};

    var userInput = GetUserInput("Do you like me? ", validResponses);

    if (userInput.Equals("Yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I like you too!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("And all along I thought you had good taste.");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Here's a sample run of the program. I had to include several screenshots since the response (and then the error message) are cleared on each iteration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

CheckWord();
Console.ReadKey();
}

    private static void CheckWord()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string errorMessage = "Error: invalid input ... enter a valid entry";
            string word = Console.ReadLine(); 
            if (word != "word")
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(word.Length +1 , (Console.CursorTop) - 1);
                Console.Write(errorMessage);
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
                for (int i = 0; i <= word.Length + errorMessage.Length +1 ; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
            }
            else
            {

                break;
            }
        }
    }
```