# please, help me to delete my text in console for C#

Tags: c#

I have the code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello С#!");
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

How to delete in console "Hello С#!" and print a new line in console?
Thank in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console

Comment: @mike Jairath gives your answer

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wurmA3 - the code in your sample appears to work fine, it clears the console.

Comment: `Console.CursorLeft`, `Console.CursorTop` to operate with cursor's position where(new text will appear)

Answer (score 0):

Call this function whenever you want to clear a line

```
public static void ClearLine()
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *place cursor* at the desired position and (over)write the text

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
  Console.Clear();

  int left = Console.CursorLeft;
  int top = Console.CursorTop;

  Console.WriteLine("Remove me!");      // <- We'll remove this
  Console.WriteLine("Hello С#!");       // <- But we'll spare this
  Console.ReadLine();

  int currentLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
  int currentTop = Console.CursorTop;

  Console.CursorLeft = left;
  Console.CursorTop = top;

  Console.Write("Sorry, I mean \"Hello Console!\"");

  Console.CursorLeft = currentLeft;
  Console.CursorTop = currentTop;

  Console.Write("That's nice now!");

  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `Console.Write` instead of `WriteLine` you can use `\r`.

```
Console.Write("Hello С#!");
Console.Write("\r...I mean... Hello World!");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Otherwise, see [Can Console.Clear be used to only clear a line instead of whole console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console) as others suggested.