# How to access the console screen buffer in c#

Tags: c#, console, stdout

I've been trying to find a way to access and edit the c# console screen buffer for a terminal based text editor, and I would rather not have to "redraw" the screen every time I need to update it.

I have tried getting the stdout stream with `Console.OpenStandardOutput()`  and resetting the position but I get: `System.NotSupportedException: Stream does not support seeking.`

Any insight on how to do this would be amazing.

Comment: If you can bear it (and you're running under Windows) you can use P/Invoke to call `WriteConsole`: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/WriteConsole.html

Comment: I wrote an answer for something similar a while back. It's still relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70072916/6594467 It uses `Kernel32.WriteConsoleOutput`.

Comment: Ideally it would not be exclusively a windows application.